# Fetching HTML data from page behind a (non-compulsory) login screen for use in Yahoo! Pipe

Tags: html, web-scraping, pipe, yql, yahoo-pipes

I have tried to use the Fetch Page module in Yahoo Pipes to grab the content of the page below to no avail:

[Example link](http://logis.korail.go.kr/getcarinfo.do?car_no=8201)

The problem being, when you first visit the page in your browser, you are presented with the option to login, and this is the page that the Yahoo! Pipes Fetch Page module fetches. However, upon refreshing the page within your browser, the login screen is replaced with a page containing a table, which contains the information I'm looking to extract.

Is there a way to bring up the "second" page, maybe using YQL, or some form of script within another webpage, that fetchess the HTML from the page containing the data, so I can use that in my Pipe?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The target page sets a browser cookie for session tracking/validation  and Yahoo Pipes or YQL cannot handle them.

You will need to ask about using **cURL** on a PHP webserver or the Google App Engine to fetch the data because cURL also has the ability to store any cookies sent to it and if needed reply with custom ones.